# Why does R.Version() return a "language" string?

Tags: r

This probably seems like a very silly question, but I am at a loss as to why `R.Version()` returns a string for `$language` (which [according to the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/base/versions/3.6.2/topics/R.Version) is always `R`). Is there a historical reason for this inclusion? It seems pretty obvious that the language is R!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The best I can do is to say it was present in the initial check-in to version control of `src/main/version.c` as of September 18, 1997: see [here](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blame/e63b67d98ba57c018924d47ee309b0e982009477/src/main/version.c#L66-L67).

My only guess is that maybe (???) there was some possibility of needing to disambiguate between code that was being run in [S(-PLUS)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/S_(programming_language)) vs. R (a great deal of S and R code would be interoperable, and lots of people would be porting code between the two systems in those days).

Other than asking an R contributor who was present that far back (e.g., Martin Maechler or Peter Dalgaard), I don't think there will be any objective answer forthcoming.

Comment: comment in answer (correctly) deleted: I wish StackOverflow had an [archaeology] tag ... the [history] tag description says "Questions about the history of programming are off-topic. ", so maybe that means this whole question is off-topic ...

Comment: FYI: There is a [Retrocomputing.SE] site. As a history major, I also appreciate archaeology questions, but that tag would be more of a meta-tag than a classificatory tag, so it doesn't make much sense to have it here.

Comment: Thanks @BenBolker, I realise these are hard things to answer objectively, but the R versus S+ distinction is a good enough explanation to satisfy my curiosity. And yes, the warning on the [history] tag scared me away, but these things are fun to think about. Maybe [development-history]? Not sure.

Comment: I took a brief look through the source code of the MASS and nlme packages (which both predate R) for the string `"S"` but didn't find anything ...